# Windows firewall blocking C# application in debug mode

Tags: c#, firewall

So until recently i have been testing my program which uses async sockets to send and receive data without problems but today suddenly it stoped working. After a lot of wasted time testing stuff and figuring out why the old version with practicly identical source code(copyed whole project folder) worked. Finnaly i figured out that windows firewall decided, for whatever reason, to block the exe again. If i go to the project folder and run is as admin it works fine (after accepting the firewall warning), but when i run it from within VS2010 in debug mode i get no warning and stuff just doesnt work.

So how do i allow the application when its running in debug mode through the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

You say it works if you run the exe as an administrator, so what happens if you run Visual Studio as an administrator?

Comment: Found another solution just now, i renamed the folder name of the project and it works again

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it with renaming the project folder in Projects/ and it worked again without any need to allow the program through the firewall again